# Persist data while switching from one tab to another in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React router for making tabs.

I am stuck to solve one scenario, scenario is something like, say we have two tabs **TabX** and **TabY**. In TabX, I have made a form which takes some data as input. I have made a button `Next`. on click of that **button** I am sending parameters to another **TabY** using `history.push`.

Now, when I switch back to **TabX**, I will lose all my data filled earlier.

I am not able to find out way so that if I switch back to another tab, data will not be lost.
One more thing, I don't want to use redux.

Answer (score 3):

In order to accomplish what you want you have to keep the state outside of the component that is being mounted and unmounted (TabX). Because you don't want to use a state container like redux, I would recommend to lift the state up. Read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to overcome this would be to use React Router Link.
With Link, you can pass a 'state' field, you can store your data in here, and then also do the same to return the data back the other way.

You can access this 'state' from this.props.history

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not very efficient as you have to send it backward and forward for no reason, better lift the state or use a store like redux

Comment: This is just an alternative way to solve the problem. Considering the post says, they don't want to use Redux. But yes, having a parent component manage the state of all Tabs would be a better approach.

Comment: If you do not want to use Redux state lifting is the best pratice reccomended by facebook itself: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html